# How to make a button in DataGrid control open a file path on the same row?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a project management system, and I have a button in each Datagrid row. The button when clicked is supposed to open the file that you have the that specific row's "path" column. how am i supposed to do this. is there a way to make each row a control or something?

[image: picture of project]

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Blender_Project_manager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Maindata.Rows.Add(addname.Text, addpath.Text);
        }

        private void Maindata_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

I tried doing

```
private void Maindata_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path.ToString());
}
```

but it just ended up giving me an error. "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: In `Maindata_CellContentClick`, you can check if the clicked column is your button column, then get the value form the file path column, and open the file. `e.RowIndex` is the row index,  `e.ColumnIndex` is the column index of clicked cell, `(string)MainData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[ name or index of file column].Value` gives the value of the file cell.

Comment: Try this syntax for opening the file:  `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);` I'll also post a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post has several related questions:

- How to avoid error `The system cannot find the file specified`
- Is there a way to make each row a control or something?
- How to make a button in DataGrid control
- How to make a button open a file path on the same row

There might be a simple solution to avoiding the exception. Try this syntax for opening the file:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);
```

Since it's hard to say exactly where the problem might be, I will also offer a comprehensive answer to your questions.

[image: screenshot]
**Playing card images credit:** [Boardgame pack v2](https://opengameart.org/content/boardgame-pack) (Creative Commons License) by Kenney Vleugels.

---

**Locating files**

If the files are part of the install (known at compile time), they can be reliably located by setting the "Copy to Output Directory" property and referencing them as

```
path =
    Path.Combine(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        "Images",
        "boardgamePack_v2",
        "PNG",
        "Cards",
        "shortFileName.png" // Example filename
    );
```

[image: copy-if-newer]

On the other hand, if they can be modified by the user, they belong in

```
path =        
    Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
        "AppName", // Example app name
        "Images",
        "boardgamePack_v2",
        "PNG",
        "Cards",
        "shortFileName.png" // Example filename
    ));
```

---

**Define row behavior**

In order to *"make each row a [...] something"* requires a class that has public properties corresponding to the columns in the DataGridView. This class will be bound to the `DataSource` property of the DataGridView, for example by making a `BindingList<Card>`. Here's a minimal example:

```
class Card
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public Image Image{ get; set; }

    internal static string ImageBaseFolder { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string GetFullPath() => Path.Combine(ImageBaseFolder, FilePath);
}
```

---

**Making a button in grid control**

In this sample a DataGridView control gets initialized in the method that loads the MainForm. Since there is no property of the class corresponding to the Open column, we will have to add it after the columns have been auto-generated from the binding. A handler is added that we can inspect to determine whether a button has been clicked.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Card.ImageBaseFolder = 
            Path.Combine(
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                "Images",
                "boardgamePack_v2",
                "PNG",
                "Cards"
            );
    }
    internal BindingList<Card> Cards { get; } = new BindingList<Card>();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        dataGridViewCards.DataSource = Cards;

        #region F O R M A T    C O L U M N S
        Cards.Add(new Card()); // <- Auto generate columns
        dataGridViewCards.Columns["Name"].AutoSizeMode= DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridViewCards.Columns["FilePath"].AutoSizeMode= DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridViewCards.Columns["FilePath"].HeaderText = "File Path";
        DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = (DataGridViewImageColumn) dataGridViewCards.Columns["Image"];
        imageColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;
        imageColumn.Width = 100;
        imageColumn.HeaderText = string.Empty;

        // Add the button column (which is not auto-generated).
        dataGridViewCards.Columns.Insert(2, new DataGridViewButtonColumn
        {
            Name = "Open",
            HeaderText = "Open",
        });
        Cards.Clear();
        #endregion F O R M A T    C O L U M N S

        // Add a few cards
        Cards.Add(new Card(Value.Ten, Suit.Diamonds));
        Cards.Add(new Card(Value.Jack, Suit.Clubs));
        Cards.Add(new Card(Value.Queen, Suit.Diamonds));
        Cards.Add(new Card(Value.King, Suit.Clubs));
        Cards.Add(new Card(Value.Ace, Suit.Hearts));

        dataGridViewCards.ClearSelection();

        // Detect click on button or any other cell.
        dataGridViewCards.CellContentClick += onAnyCellContentClick;
    }
```

---

**Make a button open a file path on the same row**

In the handler, retrieve the card from the bound collection by index and get the full path. You may have better luck with the `Process.Start` if you use the syntax shown:

```
    private void onAnyCellContentClick(object? sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridViewCards.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Open"))
        {
            var card = Cards[e.RowIndex];
            var path = card.GetFullPath();
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/select-path-from-dgv.git) a working minimal example.